# What is the cleanest port of this C# to Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am parsing a comma separated string into an array.  In C# I have:

```
var someArray = someString.Split(
    new char[] { ',' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var something in someArray)
{
    SomeList.Add(something.Trim().ToLower());
}
```

Here is what I have so far in Ruby using Rails .blank?

```
some_array = some_string.split(',').each { |something| something.strip.downcase }
some_array.delete_if { |something| something.blank? }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The code you have as written doesn't do what you expect. You call `.each` and call non-mutating methods on the strings. As a result, your `some_array` is the same as `some_string.split(',')`.

b) I would personally do this:

```
arr = str.split(',').map{ |s| s.blank? ? nil : s.strip.downcase }.compact
```

This creates an array that may have nil entries, which are then removed with "compact". If absolute speed is of the essence, though, this will be faster:

```
arr = []
str.split(',').each do |s|
  arr << s.strip.downcase unless s.blank?
end
```

**Edit**: modified code to defer `.strip.downcase` until after testing for blankness.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why it's wrong with the non-mutating.  Your answer is close to what I was looking at; jam a nil in there and compact it afterwards.

Comment: Both of your answers work.  I ended up going with the second one with the each block in one line without reassigning to s and everything looks good.  Thanks.

Comment: blank? should capture whitespace strings, so could we move the strip into the conditional?

Answer (score 3):

```
some_string.split(',').map(&:strip).map(&:downcase).reject(&:empty?)
```

This creates three intermediary arrays, and traverses all of three of them, but I wouldn't generally worry about that unless you can actually prove via performance profiling that it is a serious bottleneck.

Otherwise you'd have to do something like

```
some_string.split(',').inject([]) {|ary, str|
  ary.tap { unless (str = str.strip.downcase).empty? then ary << str end }
}
```

---

Sidenote: I'd probably have written that C# code more like this:

```
var someList = new List<string>(
    from s in someString.Split(
        new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    select s.Trim().ToLower());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Agreed not going to pre-optimize just trying to port it.  That C# is fugly.

Comment: If you wanted to golf it and save iterating twice through the same array: `some_string.split(',').reject(&:empty?).map { |e| e.strip.downcase }`

Comment: Something is off, it very well could be my code, but an input of 'first, second, thirD  , ' yields 4 items in the array instead of 3.  There is a "" item at the end that the C# version did not return.  Can anyone verify that?

Comment: @blu: It's kind of hard to figure out the exact edge cases of your C# code, since you neither specified them nor provided test cases nor does the code you posted actually work. However, after fixing it, I get a list of four elements including an empty string as the last element, just like my code does.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg: I am a big fan of point-free style. I don't like inventing names for variables that don't deserve names. Naming is hard, giving something a name elevates it to a level of importance it doesn't necessarily deserve.

Comment: You could put the downcase earlier, having `some_string.downcase` rather than `.map(&:downcase)`. Is that called commutativity?